# Can you safely manipulate the DOM with Sharepoint (MOSS 2007)and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, dom-manipulation

We have a MOSS 2007 installation where we rely on jQuery to handle automatic rotation of tabs in webparts, animation of sliding menus and tool panels.  Intermittently we get the "Operation Aborted" error with our IE 6 users.

While we confirmed that this results from manipulating the DOM before it has been completely loaded on the client, we are searching for work arounds.  Has anyone experienced this issue in Sharepoint, and what steps did you take to allow the safe execution of jQuery?  Should we be concerned that Sharepoint Core UI.js is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surpised if this is addressed in the upcoming SP2, due out next Tuesday I believe.

One can hope...

As a corollary, you can check out Jan Tielen's blog. He is legit when it comes to MOSS and jQuery.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/default.aspx